# my boolean function returns true then false?

Tags: c, cs50, boolean-operations

My boolean function should return true when it finds a "needle" but even if it does it returns false and prints out "didn't find needle"
I tried to debug with GDB, it turns out it actually returns true but then returns false afterwards without breaking after condition is met ??

Here's my code:

```
int FindMidPoint(int array[],int size)
{
int i = size / 2;
int Midpoint = array[i];
return Midpoint;
}


bool search(int value, int array[], int n)
{
// TODO: implement a searching algorithm
if ( n <= 0 )
return false; 

int Midpoint = FindMidPoint(array,n);
int mid = n / 2;
int x = round(mid);
int *firsthalf = malloc((x) * sizeof(int));
int *secondhalf = malloc((x) * sizeof(int));
memcpy(firsthalf,array, x * sizeof(int));
memcpy(secondhalf,array + x, x * sizeof(int));

if (value == Midpoint)
    {
    return true;
    }
else if (value > Midpoint)
        {
        search (value,secondhalf,mid);

        }
else if (value < Midpoint)
        {
        search(value,firsthalf,mid);    
        }
return false;
}
```

Here's what GDB gives me:

```
Starting program: /root/cs50/pset3/hacker3/find/find 10

 haystack[0] = 10

haystack[1] = 12

haystack[2] = 14

haystack[3] = 6

haystack[4] = 8


haystack[5] = 20


haystack[6] = 200


haystack[7] = 2000


haystack[8] = 202


haystack[9] = 


 6 


 8 


 10 


 12 


 14 


 20 


 200 


 202 


 2000 


Breakpoint 1, search (value=10, array=0x7ffffffbe100, n=9) at 
helpers.c:32

32      if ( n <= 0 )

(gdb) n

35      int Midpoint = FindMidPoint(array,n);

(gdb) n

36      int mid = n / 2;

(gdb) n

37      int x = round(mid);

(gdb) n

38      int *firsthalf = malloc((x) * sizeof(int));

(gdb) n

39      int *secondhalf = malloc((x) * sizeof(int));

(gdb) n

40      memcpy(firsthalf,array, x * sizeof(int));

(gdb) n

41      memcpy(secondhalf,array + x, x * sizeof(int));

(gdb) n

43      if (value < Midpoint)

(gdb) n

45          search(value,firsthalf,mid);    

(gdb) n


Breakpoint 1, search (value=10, array=0x405850, n=4) at helpers.c:32

32      if ( n <= 0 )

(gdb) n

35      int Midpoint = FindMidPoint(array,n);

(gdb) n

36      int mid = n / 2;

(gdb) n

37      int x = round(mid);

(gdb) n

38      int *firsthalf = malloc((x) * sizeof(int));

(gdb) n

39      int *secondhalf = malloc((x) * sizeof(int));

(gdb) n

40      memcpy(firsthalf,array, x * sizeof(int));

(gdb) n

41      memcpy(secondhalf,array + x, x * sizeof(int));

(gdb) n

43      if (value < Midpoint)

(gdb) info locals

Midpoint = 10

mid = 2

x = 2

firsthalf = 0x405890

secondhalf = 0x4058b0

(gdb) n

47      else if (value > Midpoint)

(gdb) info locals

Midpoint = 10

mid = 2

x = 2

firsthalf = 0x405890

secondhalf = 0x4058b0

(gdb) n

52      else if (value == Midpoint)

(gdb) n

54          return true;

(gdb) n

64  }

(gdb) n

search (value=10, array=0x7ffffffbe100, n=9) at helpers.c:46

46          }

(gdb) n

62      return false;

(gdb) n

64  }

(gdb) 

main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe238) at find.c:69

69          printf("\nDidn't find needle in haystack.\n\n");

(gdb) 


Didn't find needle in haystack.


70          return 1;
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code or maybe my understanding of boolean functions, please help!

Comment: When you do your recursive calls to `search`, what do you return then?

Comment: no it doesn't , but what path returns nothing?

Comment: You have plenty of memory leaks in your code as well. You do many allocations with `malloc`, but you never free the memory with `free`.

Answer (score 2):

The `search` function only returns `true` if the following condition is met *on the very first call*:

```
value == Midpoint
```

All of the recursive calls are made, but their results are ignored and `false` is always returned:

```
else if (value > Midpoint)
{
    search(value,secondhalf,mid);
}
else if (value < Midpoint)
{
    search(value,firsthalf,mid);    
}
return false;
```

You need to return the result from the recursion:

```
else if (value > Midpoint)
{
    return search(value,secondhalf,mid);
}
else if (value < Midpoint)
{
    return search(value,firsthalf,mid);    
}
return false;
```

Comment: it worked but sorry I didn't fully understand, excuse my ignorance.
without your edit, everything worked fine, it got to the midpoint which meets the value of the needle and then returns true ( in the gdb environment) but then it searches AGAIN and skips all the conditions and then returns false... why?

Comment: @DiaaAlaa A function only returns a value if you explicitly have a `return` statement in it. If you don't do `return search(...)` you will just ignore the result of the recursive call.

Comment: @DiaaAlaa: Well, just look it a very small part of the code.  When you first call `search()` (at the top of the recursion tree) and `value > Midpoint` is true, what do you expect to be returned and why?  Do you expect the value of `search(value,secondhalf,mid)` to be returned?  How would that happen without a `return` statement?

Comment: I expect it to return     true as the return value of the function ? doesnt this how bool functions work ?

Comment: @DiaaAlaa: It's only going to return on a line with a `return` statement.

Comment: my understanding is that every condition if not met returns false by default , and when its met it returns true and that it.

Comment: @David I understand now just dont really get the logic. but thanks a mile sir.

Comment: @DiaaAlaa As I said before, you can only return a value from a function if you explicitly have a `return` statement. If you don't have a `return` statement then the function will not return.